# AngularJS XML parsing from url

Tags: javascript, html, xml, angularjs

I managed to set up Angular, but now need to parse XML, which goes with url "/api/customers". I found the tutorial and used some code from it, but still there is no result. My script is:

```
 angular.module('myApp.service', []).
factory('DataSource', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        get: function(file,callback,transform){
            $http.get(
                file,
                {transformResponse:transform}
            ).
            success(function(data, status) {
                console.log("Request succeeded");
                callback(data);

            }).
            error(function(data, status) {
                console.log("Request failed " + status);
                $scope.customers = "fiiib";
            });

        }           
    }
}]);


 angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.service'])
.controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'DataSource', function ($scope, DataSource) {

var SOURCE_FILE = base_url+ "/api/customers.xml";

xmlTransform = function (data) {
    console.log("transform data");
    var x2js = new X2JS();
    var json = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
    return json.ArrayOfCustomer.Customers.Customer;
};


setData = function (data) {
    $scope.dataSet = data;
};


DataSource.get(SOURCE_FILE, setData, xmlTransform);
}]);
```

, my Ng-controller in html is:

```
 <div ng-controller="AppController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="Customer in dataSet">
                <div class="resultwrapper">
                    <h2>{{Customer.Address}}</h2>
                    <h3>First name {{Customer.FirstName}}</h3>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <h3>2+3= {{3+2}}</h3>        
    </div>
```

And xml structure like .... etc.
Have you got any idea, what exactly do I miss?

Comment: the issue is in parsing xml or getting xml ? Have you checked that you are getting valid xml in response ? Can you also provide console logs, if there is any error ?

Comment: there are no errors in visual studio console so far... but how can I check if I get anything with angular? I am entirely new to JavaScript

Comment: do you get this log in console "Request succeeded" ?

Comment: no, I do not see it, but I do not see "Request failed" also..